# Third Party Library for GWT validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, parsley.js, jsni

I want to validate the gwt field like (Email,Text Length,Phone Number,Date & SSN,etc..) Is there any proven JS or Library Available for Validating this fields with GWT.

- I Can't use `GWT Validation Framework` or `GWT Errai` for my application since i am getting response as JSON not DTO.
- Even I tried `Parsley JS`(http://parsleyjs.org/ ) which is not possible (Reason:GWT have {key,value} pair to set the attribute but parsley have only value.)

  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default library for this. Since you have JSON response you can create JSO objects on GWT Client side and roll up your own favourite javascript checks via JSNI code.

Reference - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html

Comment: thnks...Is there any third party Js or library available for validation